# Extract first N elements from every row of a 2D NumPy array, with variable N, and concatenate into 1D array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given a 2D NumPy array, e.g.

```
array([[22, 66, 16, 17, 79],
       [17,  5, 27, 58, 79],
       [ 7, 41, 66, 82, 48]])
```

And a 1D array specifying how many elements starting from the first index of each row to keep, e.g.

```
array([3, 4, 1])
```

Extract these elements and concatenate them into a 1D array:

```
array([22, 66, 16, 17, 5, 27, 58, 7])
```

i.e.

```
array([[22, 66, --, --, --],
       [17,  5, 27, 58, --],
       [ 7, --, --, --, --]])
```

Is there a pure NumPy implementation of this operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a straight forward solution - with a list comprehension:

```
In [8]: arr = np.array([[22, 66, 16, 17, 79],
   ...:        [17,  5, 27, 58, 79],
   ...:        [ 7, 41, 66, 82, 48]])

In [9]: idx = np.array([3,4,1])

In [10]: np.hstack([row[:i] for row, i in zip(arr,idx)])
Out[10]: array([22, 66, 16, 17,  5, 27, 58,  7])
```

A boolean mask approach:

```
In [11]: np.arange(5)<idx[:,None]
Out[11]: 
array([[ True,  True,  True, False, False],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True, False],
       [ True, False, False, False, False]])

In [12]: arr[np.arange(5)<idx[:,None]]
Out[12]: array([22, 66, 16, 17,  5, 27, 58,  7])
```

timings

```
In [13]: timeit np.hstack([row[:i] for row, i in zip(arr,idx)])
19 µs ± 29.1 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [14]: timeit arr[np.arange(5)<idx[:,None]]
11.3 µs ± 17.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solutions (`arr` is your array of values, `idxs` is your array of indexes):

```
from itertools import starmap

import numpy as np

x = np.arange(arr.shape[0]) * arr.shape[1]
result = arr.flatten()[np.hstack(list(starmap(np.arange, zip(x, x + idxs))))]
```

Here is the result:

```
>>> result
array([22, 66, 16, 17,  5, 27, 58,  7])
```